# Is this stdClass value standard or specific to my case

Tags: php, soap

I am uniting PHP and Intersystems Cache via SOAP. Cache in server, PHP is SOAP client.
I call function ForecastResult and get result.

This is what I see, when do var_dump() -

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["ForecastResult"]=> int(221) }
```

My question - is int() wrapping in text is PHP job or such result is returned and I need to parce it?
I tried `$array = (array)$class;`, but same value of int(221) appear.

My desired result is 221.
In case of method Test that return string type, I get -

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["TestResult"]=> string(4) "Test" }
```

And my desired result is "Test" without string(4) predicate.

Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("./client.wsdl");

$result = $client->Test();

var_dump($result); 
echo "<br>";

$result = $client->Forecast("76");

var_dump($result);
$result = (array)$result;

var_dump($result["ForecastResult"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the output of `var_dump()` tells you that you can access the desired information in this manner:

```
echo $result->ForecastResult; // 221
echo $result->TestResult; // Test
```

Comment: I never knew it. Silly question :)